# Why did Natasha say "any day now" here?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

In *Black Widow* (2021), Natasha and Yelena escapes from Black Widows. They
saw some bikes parked near a building:

> Natasha: Which one's yours?
>
> Yelena: Black. Brown seat. Where are my keys?

*Natasha takes out keys from her pocket*:

> Natasha: **Any day now**.

Natasha drives the bike with Yelena sitting behind.

Why did Natasha say "any day now" here? Which means "very soon"
in simple English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Natasha is being sarcastic about the amount of time that Yelena is taking. In English this [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/any+day+now) also means "*hurry up!*".

The script could just as easily read

> [Natasha takes out keys from her pocket:]
>
> **Natasha:** We need to leave urgently, so please can you get on the bike instead of staring at the carnage that we're trying to get away from.

Note that Yelena returns the favour a few seconds later with a similarly sarcastic...

> "Any time now, please"